# Generate list of users based on field in related profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a user model and a profile model, I want to return the list of users whose Is_teacher == true in the profile

Here is my model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is my view.py

```
def tutorlist(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(user.profile.is_teacher == True)

    return render(request, 'home/tutor_list.html', {'users': users})
```

How do I return the users whose profile == true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django allows you to [span lookups over relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

This will work:

```py
users = User.objects.filter(profile__is_teacher=True)
```

Note the syntax inside `filter`, so `__` instead of `.` and `=` instead of `==`. This is something to get used to and well explained in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups). Certainly worth having a look!

Answer (score 0):

true_profiles = [user in users if users.profile.is_teacher == True]

will loop through all users and add users whose profile.is_teacher attribute is true.